# Is Borden's secret revealed as soon as the 11th minute of the movie?

Tags: the-prestige

In the film The Prestige, Borden's secret is that

> He has a twin brother.

Watching the movie for the second time, I noticed a man looking just like Christian Bale sitting next to Borden at the beginning of the scene where Angier and Borden appear as assistants.

Am I mistaken, or is the secret revealed as soon in the movie?

[image: A man looking like Borden is sitting next to him in the theater]

Comment: Foreshadowed, perhaps. But revealed? Would you have noticed him if you hadn't already known the twist?

Comment: Wait. Wasn't Borden played by Bale? Wouldn't it be Borden's secret?

Comment: @phantom42 Yeah, sorry, I'll edit that.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan I wouldn't have noticed, but this is the thing with the clues, you don't notice them the first time, right? That's why I think you always enjoy a movie more the secondtime you see it.

Comment: Exactly. It's a *clue*, yes, but doesn't *reveal* the secret.

Comment: So, shouldn't the picture here be behind a spoiler tag?

Comment: While it would really be great if it was actually forshadowed this way (and the question isn't too bad), I really think you're making too much out of a slight similarity. But who knows.

Comment: When I was watching the movie the prestige, I partly attracted and interested in Bernard Fallon's character's performance. Then I searched web to find the actor... Wonderfully I didn't find a special actor, I wondered a lot. I continued watching ...
And at the end, I found at which I hadn't watched CLOSELY ...!!
This already had happened to me once, when I was watching the movie "Fight Club" and I wanted to find the name of Edward Norton's character inside the movie. But I couldn't even after searching in Internet ...
Bravo Mr. Nolan, Bravo
Thank you, Mr. Nolan

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This has been unanswered for too long, so I'm just going to say it. **NO.** That is not him.

Beyond throwing CGI money away on such an inconsequential shot, if you look at the other man's features you'll notice much different bone and cartilage structures around the eye sockets, more-centered zygomatic bones (cheekbones), and a more acute angle where the nasal bones indent and leave the brow. Plus, this man looks nothing like The Professor / Bernard Fallon (Borden's alter-ego).

I see no reason to assume this is anything other than someone reading too much into a slight resemblance. Do I have definitive proof? No, I do not. Also, I have difficulty in seeing any kind of compelling resemblance between the two men.

Another thing to consider is that the twins kept public contact at a minimum. They did not seem to "hang out" together. This is explained by Borden's reveal of the so-called "frail" old Chinese magician whose act was basically performed off-stage; ie: the man was fit enough to work heavy bowls of water but presented himself as a feeble old man who required canes and / or assistance to go to and from the theater. That was the real act. Borden would not likely risk exposure by sitting next to himself.

Comment: +1 - You're not *"just saying it"*, you provide some very reasonable arguments for your claim as well.

Comment: Well I guess the resemblance was subjective